# With Ansible, is it possible to connect connect to hosts that are behind Cloud IAP (Identity-Aware Proxy) in GCP?

Tags: ssh, ansible, google-cloud

Cloud IAP is a sort of proxy for Google Cloud Platform that lets you connect to compute instances that don't have public IP addresses, without a VPN. You stand up an instance and then you can use the `gcloud` utility to connect to it by name like so: `gcloud compute ssh my-server-01`. This handles authenticating you through the proxy and logging you into the target server with your own Google account (using a feature called OS Login).

I figure to make ansible do what the `gcloud` tool is doing I would need a custom connection plugin.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58034730/320399

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After discussion on https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/e9ve5q/ansible_slow_as_a_hell_with_gcp_iap_any_way_to/ I altered solution to use an SSH connection sharing via socket.

It is two times faster then @mat solution. I put it on our PROD. **Here is an implementation that doesn't depend on host name patterns!**

The proper solution is to use Bastion/Jump host because `gcloud` command still spawns Python interpreter that spawns `ssh` - it is still inefficient!

`ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
pipelining = True
ssh_executable = misc/gssh.sh
ssh_args =
transfer_method = piped

[privilege_escalation]
become = True
become_method = sudo

[defaults]
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python
gathering = False
# Somehow important to enable parallel execution...
strategy = free
```

`gssh.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ansible/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py
# exec_command(self, cmd, in_data=None, sudoable=True) calls _build_command(self, binary, *other_args) as:
#   args = (ssh_executable, self.host, cmd)
#   cmd = self._build_command(*args)
# So "host" is next to the last, cmd is the last argument of ssh command.

host="${@: -2: 1}"
cmd="${@: -1: 1}"

# ControlMaster=auto & ControlPath=... speedup Ansible execution 2 times.
socket="/tmp/ansible-ssh-${host}-22-iap"

gcloud_args="
--tunnel-through-iap
--zone=europe-west1-b
--quiet
--no-user-output-enabled
--
-C
-o ControlMaster=auto
-o ControlPersist=20
-o PreferredAuthentications=publickey
-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no
-o PasswordAuthentication=no
-o ConnectTimeout=20"

exec gcloud compute ssh "$host" $gcloud_args -o ControlPath="$socket" "$cmd"
```

**UPDATE** There is response from Google engineer that `gcloud` aren't supposed to be called **in parallel**! See ["gcloud compute ssh" can't be used in parallel](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149709703)

Experiments were shown that with Ansible `fork=5` I almost always hit an error. With `fork=2` I've never experienced one.

**UPDATE 2** Time passed and as of end of 2020 I can run `gcloud compute ssh` in parallel (in WSL I did `fork = 10`) without locking errors.

Comment: I took a slightly different approach for handling the argument parsing by taking passing all but the last two arguments as `--ssh-flag` options: https://gist.github.com/acdha/f1969b9fe9ef449571daae3c4b1aeebb#file-gcp-ssh-wrapper-L16

I also opened an issue about requiring the kludge to re-specify the zone since there doesn't appear to be a great way to pull that from the Ansible inventory and it's annoying to have to repeat a value the API returns: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/157498448

Answer (score 6):

I figured out a way to make this work without a connection plugin. Basically you can write a script that wraps the `gcloud` tool and point the `ansible_ssh_executable` parameter at this script, which you can define at the inventory level. You do need to make sure the `gcp_compute` inventory plugin identifies hosts by name, because this is what `gcloud compute ssh` expects.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -o errexit
# Wraps the gcloud utility to enable connecting to instances which are behind
# GCP Cloud IAP. Used by setting the `ansible_ssh_executable` setting for a play
# or inventory. Parses out the relevant information from Ansible's call to the
# script and injects into the right places of the gcloud utility.

arg_string="$@"

grep_hostname_regex='[a-z]*[0-9]\{2\}\(live\|test\)'
sed_hostname_regex='[a-z]*[0-9]{2}(live|test)'

target_host=$(
  echo "$arg_string\c" | grep -o "$grep_hostname_regex"
)

ssh_args=$(
  echo "$arg_string\c" | sed -E "s# ${sed_hostname_regex}.*##"
)

cmd=$(
  echo "$arg_string\c" | sed -E "s#.*${sed_hostname_regex} ##"
)

gcloud compute ssh "$target_host" \
  --command="$cmd" \
  --tunnel-through-iap \
  -- $ssh_args
```

Note:

- This is tested on macOS. The `sed` options might be different on Linux, for example.
- The "host" regexes will need to fit your naming convention. If you don't have a consistent naming convention that would work like it does for me you'll need to find some other way to parse out the information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very useful!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for posting these @gavenkoa and @matt.  One suggestion is to add the following so you don't need to hard code the zone.

Snippet:

```
ZONE=$(gcloud compute instances list --filter="name:${host}" --format='value(zone)')

gcloud_args="
--tunnel-through-iap \
--zone=${ZONE}
```

Comment: Cool. One note that extra command might introduce annoying delays. I work with Windows WSL env, it is noticeable here (( Also you can replace `gcloud compute instances list`  with `gcloud compute instances describe $host --format='value(zone)'`. For me that commands adds 2.6s delay. Ansible calls SSH client for each task / each host. 10 hosts * 10 tasks give 260s of delay. I would keep that info in the inventory or try to load it with https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_info_module.html (service secret key is required in that case)

Comment: I tried `gcloud compute instances describe $host --format='value(zone)'` but it fails with `Could not detect which major revision of yum is in use, which is required to determine module backend.`.